# Clearing cells based on clearing/changing another cell and applying it to all rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have two tables on the same excel sheet.
The first table is named Cabinet, and its range is $A$12:$AN$29
The second table is named LaminatedBench, and its range is $A$33:$AN$50

For the table "Cabinet":

I am trying to:
When A12 is cleared/changed, clear cells: B12, C12, D12 & H12.
When B12 is cleared/changed, clear cells: C12, D12 & H12.
When C12 is cleared/changed, clear cells: D12 & H12.

Similarly:
When A13 is cleared/changed, clear cells: B13, C13, D13 & H13.
When B13 is cleared/changed, clear cells: C13, D13 & H13.
When C13 is cleared/changed, clear cells: D13 & H13.
& This applies to all the rows from Row12 to Row29.

For the table "LaminatedBench":

I am trying to:
When A33 is cleared/changed, clear cells: B33, C33, D33, E33, F33, G33, H33 & L33.
When B33 is cleared/changed, clear cells: C33, D33, E33, F33, G33, H33 & L33.
When C33 is cleared/changed, clear cells: D33, E33, F33, G33, H33 & L33.
When D33 is cleared/changed, clear cells: E33, F33, G33, H33 & L33.
When E33 is cleared/changed, clear cells: F33, G33, H33 & L33.
When F33 is cleared/changed, clear cell: G33, H33 & L33.
When F33 is cleared/changed, clear cell: H33 & L33.
& This applies to all the rows from Row33 to Row50.

I am using the below code for table 1 for the first row. I will be adding many more tables and would have to write several lines of codes for each row.

How do I adjust it without adding a line of code of each row?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
End If
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$A12")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("B12:D29").ClearContents
    Range("H12:H29").ClearContents
End If
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$B12")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("C12:C29").ClearContents
    Range("H12:H29").ClearContents
End If
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$A33")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("B33:H50").ClearContents
    Range("L33:L50").ClearContents
End If
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$B33")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("C33:H50").ClearContents
    Range("L33:L50").ClearContents
End If
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$C33")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("D33:H50").ClearContents
    Range("L33:L50").ClearContents
End If
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$D33")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("E33:H33").ClearContents
    Range("L33:L50").ClearContents
End If
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$E33")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("F33:H50").ClearContents
    Range("L33:L50").ClearContents
End If
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$F33")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("G33:H50").ClearContents
    Range("L33:L50").ClearContents
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$G33")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("H33:H50").ClearContents
    Range("L33:L50").ClearContents
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In table  Cabinet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rngDB As Range
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("a12", "c29")) Is Nothing Then
        Set rngDB = Range(Target.Offset(, 1), Range("d" & Target.Row))
        Set rngDB = Union(rngDB, Range("h" & Target.Row))
        rngDB.ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```

In LaminatedBench

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rngDB As Range
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("a33", "d50")) Is Nothing Then
        Set rngDB = Range(Target.Offset(, 1), Range("h" & Target.Row))
        Set rngDB = Union(rngDB, Range("L" & Target.Row))
        rngDB.ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! You saved my day. Genius!!

Comment: may i ask why you wrote d50 in the 4th line of the LaminatedBench code. Shouldn't it be h50 instead?

Comment: I noticed that your code for Cabinet is not deleting D12. Please advise. I even changed c29 to d29 but it didn't work.

Comment: Pls ignore my previous comment, I enabled events and it worked fine.

Comment: However, one table had three columns that I want to be cleared.
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$A96")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("B96:D113").ClearContents
    Range("H96:H113").ClearContents Your formula is not letting me type in B96 though it is clearing B96. I will post this in a new question.

Comment: I have changed this comment to a question which I have posted under the same title? Could you please search for my question and try to answer it, please? I am using your code; it looks like it just needs a tiny adjustment for the smaller table I recently created.

Answer (score 0):

I think your narrative for 'LaminatedBench' started to stray a little in the last two sentences of that paragraph. You seem to cover deleting F33 twice.

Put this into the worksheet's private code sheet (right-click worksheet name tab, View Code), not a public module code sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A12:C29")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo safe_exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim c As Range
        For Each c In Intersect(Target, Range("A12:C29"))
            If IsEmpty(c) Then _
                Intersect(c.Resize(1, 8), Range("A12:D29, H12:H29")).ClearContents
        Next c
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A33:G50")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo safe_exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim lb As Range
        For Each lb In Intersect(Target, Range("A33:G50"))
            If IsEmpty(lb) Then _
                Intersect(lb.Resize(1, 12), Range("A33:H50, L33:L50")).ClearContents
        Next lb
    End If

safe_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried the next formula and it worked. I didn't try yours yet. If the second formula slows down the spreadsheet I will try yours. Regardless, thank you mate!!

Comment: Do I replace c with Cabinet? and lb with LaminatedBench