# VBA clearing cells based on clearing/changing another cell and applying it to all rows

Tags: vba, excel

have two tables on the same excel sheet. The first table is named Cabinet, and its range is $A$12:$AN$29 The second table is named WallTiles, and its range is $A$96:$AN$113

For the table "Cabinet":

I am trying to create a macro, that allows the following: When A12 is cleared/changed, clear cells: B12, C12, D12 & H12. When B12 is cleared/changed, clear cells: C12, D12 & H12. When C12 is cleared/changed, clear cells: D12 & H12.

Similarly: When A13 is cleared/changed, clear cells: B13, C13, D13 & H13. When B13 is cleared/changed, clear cells: C13, D13 & H13. When C13 is cleared/changed, clear cells: D13 & H13. & This applies to all the rows from Row12 to Row29.

For the table "WallTiles:

I am trying to create a macro, that allows the following: When A96 is cleared, clear cells: B96 & F 96. This applies to all the rows from Row96 to Row113.

I am using the below code that @Dy.Lee gave me and it worked great for the Cabinet table:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rngDB As Range
If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("a12", "c29")) Is Nothing Then
    Set rngDB = Range(Target.Offset(, 1), Range("d" & Target.Row))
    Set rngDB = Union(rngDB, Range("h" & Target.Row))
    rngDB.ClearContents
End If
End Sub
```

However, When I apply it to table WallTiles, it works by clearing B and F, but it doesn't let me enter values in column B.I need to enter data in B96: B113.

```
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("a96", "b113")) Is Nothing Then
    Set rngDB = Range(Target.Offset(, 1), Range("b" & Target.Row))
    Set rngDB = Union(rngDB, Range("f" & Target.Row))
    rngDB.ClearContents
    End If
```

Please help!!

Comment: You repeated that mistake with F33 in the LaminatedBench paragraph. The second F33 should be G33. You still have '... When **F33** is cleared/changed, clear cell: H33 & L33. ...'.

Comment: @Jeeped. HI mate. Sorry, I have edited the question as it was picking up the old question. Are u able to look into it after the changes.Thanks mate.

Comment: You've copied a lot of the old question but you haven't explained what new things you want to do with the wall tiles table.

Answer (score 0):

Add this section to  the code I responded with in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51255008/vba-clearing-cells-based-on-clearing-changing-another-sell-and-applying-it-to-al/51256435#51256435).

```
'WallTiles
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A96:A113")) Is Nothing Then
    On Error GoTo safe_exit
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim wt As Range
    For Each wt In Intersect(Target, Range("A96:A113"))
        If IsEmpty(wt) Then _
            wt.Resize(1, 2).ClearContents
    Next lb
End If
```

Comment: Are you able to adjust my code? I have so many tables, and it will be very time consuming to adjust your code for all the tables that I have created (where the code I am using, which i pasted in my question, works great for others bigger tables). Please, can you give it a go?

Comment: I don't agree with that coding method. While it is considered 'best practice' to avoid triggering a worksheet_change that runs on top of itself through disabling events, that method of code actually uses it in a perverse form of loop. So, no; I'm sorry but I won;t rework that code.

Comment: If you have a lot of tables with different layouts and you cannot loop them or union them then you are just going to have to do it brick-by-brick.

Comment: Ok mate. If you think your code is better, I will start adjusting it to my needs. Thanks mate!

Comment: I am trying to adjust your code for all my other tables but I am confused as to why you used "Dim c as Range" in one code and "Dim 1b as Range" in the other two codes. Could you please advise if I should keep using 1b for all my other codes?

Comment: a) Actually, that was EL-BEE, not ONE-BEE as in **L**aminated**B**ench. b) I try not to dim a var until I know I will need it. That's why all the vars are dimmed inside the If statements. However, in your case you should probably just dim a single one at the very top and use the same one for all of the different variations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174843/discussion-between-jeeped-and-omar).

Comment: @Omar - please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51298646/running-worksheet-change-on-top-of-itself-intentionally)

Comment: I saw it and I created a spreadsheet with the same values and code you posted. The problem is once I clear a cell say D12,I can no longer enter a value in D12. When can we chat again? I am running out of time to deliver this spreadhseet.